# Evaluating proto expression tree

Tags: c++, boost-proto

I am trying to evaluate a proto expression tree with a custom defined context. I have a `struct exp_tag {}` using which a create a terminal

```
template <typename T>
inline typename proto::result_of::make_expr<exp_tag, T const &>::type
exp_t(T const &t) {
  return proto::make_expr<exp_tag>(boost::cref(t));
}
```

I create the expression tree as follows :

```
exp_t(x)
```

And the tree looks like this

```
7exp_tag( 
    terminal(6tensorILm0EE) 
)
```

In my context I evaluate the tree using function overloads like this :

```
template<typename A, typename B>
float operator()(proto::tag::plus, A& a, B& b) const {
    auto va = proto::eval(a, *this);
    auto vb = proto::eval(b, *this);
    return va + vb;
}
```

When I attempt to do this for my `exp_t`  by replacing `proto::tag::plus` with `exp_tag` my code doesn't compile.

My guess is that since `exp_t` is an expression because of `proto::make_exr<exp_tag>` I can't treat it as a `proto::tag` but I can't figure out how to do this.

What should I replace `proto::tag::plus` with in order to evaluate `exp_t` through the context?

Comment: Have you tried `float operator()(exp_tag, A& a) const`? Having a complete example would make trying to help a lot easier...